# Missing group members when retrieving group members via Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the list of members of a group via the Facebook API.  It works in principle, but it seems that there's a discrepancy between the number of members as stated on the group page (when accessed via the browser) and the number of members retrieved via the Facebook API.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Consider for instance the following group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/141499479690556

As of right now, Facebook states that there are 1165 members in that group.

Now, go to the Graph API explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and access /v2.10/**141499479690556/members?limit=1500** (I set the limit well above the number of group members here to make sure they are all in there).

As of right now, the returned *data* array only contains 1139 members.

Where are the missing 26 members?

And yes, I am absolutely sure noone "blocked" me or anything. Anyway, I tested this on several groups, even some I have never interacted with. There always appears to be a discrepancy, and the bigger the group, the bigger the discrepancy. In groups with over 5000 members, I have seen discrepancies of 100-200 people.

At first I thought there was a problem with paging (I originally used a smaller limit and used paging), but as you can see, the same problem appears even when the limit is high enough for all members to be returned at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.facebook.com/help/186433704739124

> If you're seeing a total number of members that's different from the real number, it's possible that some people in the group now have inactive accounts.
>
> When someone's account is inactive, it means that person can't be seen or found on Facebook. Even though he or she is still counted as a group member, they won't appear in the group anymore. An account can become inactive if someone chooses to deactivate it or if the account is disabled by Facebook.

Comment: (Side note: That's the first Google result for "facebook group count inaccurate".)

Comment: Could also be that the user turned of Facebook Platform. Then they will not show up in any Facebook API calls even if their account exists

Comment: Thanks for this. And yes, I've tried to google for this problem - apparently I just didn't hit the right search terms. :)

Comment: Follow-up question: Any idea how I can quickly pinpoint those inactive accounts? I'll look into it and may ask a new question about this problem in the future, but maybe you've got a good idea right now?

Comment: What do you mean by "pinpoint"? My reading of that help article is that they won't show up in any way - you won't find them in API calls or the FB UI. They're effectively invisible, and show only in the overall count.

Comment: No, I do not think so. When I go to the members page (via the FB UI) of the group from my example and keep clicking on "See More" until all members are listed, I can see all 1165 members (I determined this by pasting the resulting content into a file and using an appropriate grep command). Hence, it seems the problem only occurs when using the FB API - or else I'm facing a different problem altogether. Clearly I can now use this "manually" retrieved list and diff them with the list returned by the FB API, but this is cumbersome and doesn't scale well. Just thought there may be an easier way.

Comment: Then I suspect @WizKid's theory is your issue - folks who've turned off the FB platform.

Comment: I suppose that is the case. Thank you both for your competent and quick help.